# Need to find which capital letter occurs most often

Tags: python

I'm wondering what the best way to write a function in Python would be to find which capitalized letter occurs most often in a string, and then tell me how many times that letter occurs.

I'm messing around with using for loops, the first one going through the string, and then a nested one to go through all capitalized characters. Just trying to find out the best way to count each letter separately.

Comment: Instead of asking for the best way, why don't you try whatever you can think of and see how it works? Then, if it's too slow, too much code, etc, you can learn from what you did and try again.

Answer (score 3):

This is a very straight forward application for `collections.Counter`

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> s = 'This is A TesT String With CAPITALS'
>>> c = Counter(i for i in s if i.isupper())
>>> c
Counter({'T': 4, 'A': 3, 'S': 2, 'I': 1, 'W': 1, 'P': 1, 'L': 1, 'C': 1})
```

To do this in a more step-by-step manner

```
>>> uniqueCaps = set(filter(str.isupper, s))
>>> uniqueCaps
{'S', 'C', 'P', 'I', 'L', 'A', 'T', 'W'}

counts = dict()
for letter in uniqueCaps:
    counts[letter] = s.count(letter)

>>> counts
{'I': 1, 'S': 2, 'A': 3, 'L': 1, 'T': 4, 'C': 1, 'P': 1, 'W': 1}
```

Meeting somewhere in the middle

```
>>> counts = {letter: s.count(letter) for letter in uniqueCaps}
>>> counts
{'I': 1, 'S': 2, 'A': 3, 'L': 1, 'T': 4, 'C': 1, 'P': 1, 'W': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> string = "THIS can be DONE USING DICTIONARIES"
>>> dic={}
>>> for i in string:
...    if i.isupper():
...       dic.setdefault(i,0)
...       dic[i]+=1
... 
>>> most_common = sorted(dic.items(),key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)
>>> most_common 
[('I', 5), ('N', 3), ('S', 3), ('E', 2), ('D', 2), ('O', 2), ('T', 2), ('A', 1), ('C', 1), ('G', 1), ('H', 1), ('R', 1), ('U', 1)]
```